# How do you pluralize abbreviations of metric names (e.g. "kilo")?

Tags: grammatical-number, abbreviations

Metric names are sometimes abbreviated, e.g. Kilogram as kilo, megabyte as mega and nanosecond as nano.

Is it correct to add an "s" as suffix to the plural form of abbreviations?

For example:

> The total weight is 10 kilo.

(as kilo is here an abbreviation of kilograms)

OR

> The total weight is 10 kilos

**Note:**
The questions is restricted to the abbreviations, not the metric symbols. It's clear to me that symbols like km (for kilometers), s (for seconds), etc. do **not** end with 's' in plural.

---

**EDIT**

The first comments and answers here brought to my attention that 'mega' and 'nano' are not really common abbreviations. Moreover, they are probably incorrect. I'm sure I've heard them already, but it's possible that it was always from non-native speakers like me.  Correct common abbreviations (besides "kilo" for "kilogram") are "meg" for "megabytes" and "gig" for "gigabytes".

Comment: I've seen "kilos" used for kilograms, but that's all. I've never seen "mega" or "nano" used as an abbreviation for any measurement.

Comment: The NOAD reports _kilos_ as plural of _kilo_, but it doesn't report _megas_ as plural of _mega_.

Comment: @Bruno: Can you cite an example where these abbreviations (other than kilo) are used? Perhaps that would help in answering the question. I for one have never seen "nano" and "mega" written.

Comment: I haven't seen 'mega' as the abbreviation, but I've heard MB pronounced as both 'meg' and 'megs'.

Comment: There is also the *mil* for *milliliter* and, less commonly *millimeter*, e.g. `ten mils`, `twenty-five mils`.

Comment: If this is intended for technical writing, I'd recommend not to use abbreviations at all and write out the names of the units in full (or if you're really pressed for space, the approved abbreviations km, mg...) to ensure there is no ambiguity. Would "kilos" be "kilograms" or "kilometers"? (That was rhetorical, but you get my point...)

Comment: @Jimi *mil* is also used in engineering as an abbreviation for a thousandth of an inch. I would avoid using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am only familiar with the abbreviation of *kilogram* as *kilo*, and this is indeed pluralized as *kilos*. I have heard *mega* and *megas* from foreigners but they strike me as ungrammatical, as does *nano* from *nanosecond* (why not for *nanometer*?). Here’s what I found in the Corpus of Contemporary American English:

All the incidences of *nanos* were references to one of the following:

- [iPod nano](http://www.apple.com/ipodnano/)
- A surname *Nanos*
- In science fiction, references to something like *nanorobots*

So, *nano(s)* is not a commonly-used abbreviated form for *nanosecond* (or *nanometer*)

As for *megas*, the only examples in COCA were three uses as a name, and one use in science fiction:

> So after the Port dome went up they built this lean-to partial dome that tilts up against the Port dome like a crescent cupping a bigger arc: the Curve. It was supposed to be just warehouses and **megas**, not living space, so they didn't attach it to the Port dome very well and now the Curve pulls away from the Port dome a little more every year, and a little more gas and garbage falls into the Curve but nobody seems to give a damn.

It’s unclear from even this much context what a *mega* is, but I’m pretty sure it’s not a megabyte.

I checked also for uses of *gigas* for *gigabytes* but all the *gigas* in COCA are species names, where it presumably means “very large”: *Strombus gigas* (a sea snail), *Crassostrea gigas* (an oyster), *Angelica gigas* (a flowering plant).

So, in conclusion, don’t use *mega* as an abbreviation for *megabyte*. I understand this is common in some languages, such as Spanish, but it is not used in English. Use instead *MB* as the abbreviation for *megabyte*. However, *kilo* for *kilogram* is perfectly idiomatic, although in American English, the things most often measured in kilos are cocaine and heroin. The top 10 most common collocates for *kilo* are: *cocaine*, *hundred*, *per*, *five*, *heroin*, *fifty*, *weighed*, *pounds*, *ten*, and *half*.

**EDIT**: as pointed out in the question’s comments, *meg(s)* and *gig(s)* are the common used spoken abbreviations for *megabyte(s)* and *gigabyte(s)*.

Comment: Well to be honest kilo for kilogram technically makes just as much sense as nano for nanosecond. It could well mean kilosecond or pretty much a thousand of anything.

Comment: The way these things develop so rarely make any sense though, don't they?

Answer (score 1):

As the *New Oxford American Dictionary* reports, *kilo* is a noun used as abbreviation of *kilogram* and, rarely, of *kilometer*.
The same is not true for *mega*, which is not used as noun.
*Nano* is informally used as a noun, to mean *nanotechnology*.

Looking for *nanos* and *megas* in the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* I found that

- *nanos* is used more in fiction, and in the newspapers; in the last case, in all the cases they are referring to the iPod Nano.
- *megas* is used in fiction (*It was supposed to be just warehouses and megas, not living space, so they didn't attach it to the Port dome […].*), and magazines and newspapers; in the last case, the sentences make reference to the last name of a person (*Mr. Megas*).

Comment: I see we were looking at the same thing at the same time ;-)

Comment: I learned from you to look for a word in the _Corpus of Contemporary American English_. `:-)` (I don't know why, but I don't like to use the abbreviated name of the site.)

Comment: probably because it makes more sense for the abbreviated form to be CCAE, although that is admittedly much less catchy than COCA.

Comment: @nohat: Actually, the reason is more "botanic". **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

Both with and without the 's' seems to be common.

I buy 20 *kilos* of cement. It comes in a 20 *kilo* bag.

In Australia, the abbreviation for kilometre tends to be 'k'. One does a 5 *K* run. Sydney is a thousand *Ks* away from Melbourne.

Another common abreviation is mill, short for millimetre. From common use, it can be used with or without an 's'.  There is a 5 *mill* gap. Draw a line 5 *mills* long.

Comment: "Mill" (or "mil") can also be used as an abbreviation for millilitre, but in any event it is only used in spoken English, since in writing it is always quicker and clearer to use "mm" or "ml".

Comment: Arguably, mill (and K) are more slang than an abbreviation. Along the lines of 'click' meaning kilometres.

Answer (score 0):

All of these words are prefixes for [engineering notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation), a form of scientific notation used to represent numbers to the most significant magnitude group of ten to the power of a multiple of three - all derived from appropriate greek words.

*kilo-* is perhaps the most commonly encountered so the plural *kilos* is in common use, whereas the others are not so much.  As the other prefixes are encountered more, they are coming in to use, *megs*, *gigs*, *teras* - these large numbers coming in via space storage in computing making them mainstream.

The smaller units do not seem to have spawned the same usage.  *micros* has a use independent of its prefix, as the word *micro* has an alternative meaning; perhaps this clash prevents the use.  I have heard *nanos* used in science fiction to refer to nanoscopic robots, otherwise it has not been adapted yet.

Theoretically all the plurals are valid for derivation in the long term, it just takes time for the words to be accepted in the mainstream.

Comment: "Micron" is used as an abbreviation of "micrometre".

Comment: @Brian Nixon: Quite right, *microns* being an acceptable plural.  Interesting how the magnitude gets bound to the most common use-case for it, as with *kilos* implying mass.

Comment: I've often heard the value of a 4.7μF capacitor pronounced "four point seven mike", and 22pF pronounced "22pF".  A value of 47nF would be "point oh four seven mike".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the term "kilo" is a unit of mass equal to 1kg.  Although it is derived from "kilogram", it should be regarded as a unit of mass rather than as a term for a thousand of something.  Likewise "meg" and "gig", are terms for roughly one million, and one billion bytes, respectively, as opposed to those quantities of everything else.  The term "K" (pronounced "k") generally refers to 1,024 bytes, but may sometimes be used to refer to $1,000, or it may be used with a discrete item to indicate quantity (e.g. we need 50K fully-assembled units by next July).